# How to insert a record and make sure the entire row is unique

Tags: sql

I want to insert multiple values into a row, but I want to make sure that the row is unique, i.e. no duplicate rows.

I am unsure how to do this (it is fairly easy to if there is only a single value to check for i.e. like this: [SQL Server - How to insert a record and make sure it is unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267804/sql-server-how-to-insert-a-record-and-make-sure-it-is-unique)).

This is my code, but it won't allow me to insert unique rows as it tests for single columns and multiple columns combined.

```
CREATE TABLE myCities (
    UserID int null,
    CityID int null 
)

DECLARE @UserID int, @CityID int
SET @UserID = 1
SET @CityID = 1

INSERT INTO myCities (UserID,CityID) 
SELECT @UserID,@CityID
        WHERE 
            @UserID NOT IN ( SELECT UserID FROM myCities WHERE UserID = @UserID )
        AND 
            @CityID NOT IN ( SELECT CityID FROM myCities WHERE CityID = @CityID )
```

Comment: Are you doing insert into selects and only one user and thread at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the obvious is right at hand - solved it by using `NOT EXISTS`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO myCities (UserID,CityID) 
SELECT @UserID,@CityID
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                   SELECT UserID FROM myCities 
                   WHERE 
                   UserID = @UserID and 
                   CityID = @CityID
                 )
```

Comment: Where did you get that so quickly (as soon as you posted your question)?

Comment: Well, I figured it out while I was posting. I could have chosen not to post, but maybe somebody else could benefit from it.

Comment: Mark, OK - how would you manage that? Put it in a transaction? I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

The only sure way is to put the check in the database. In this case create a unique key on the table which will also be its primary key so

```
-- syntax for MS/Sybase at least is
ALTER TABLE myCities
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_myCities UNIQUE (UserID,CityID)
```

Then when you insert a duplicate then you will get an error and your code will have to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks - this solution won't work in my scenario because I am doing some manual one-time-only updating of various tables, copying some data around etc. My tables are fairly large (100+ million rows) - the myCities was just to illustrate my problem. Thanks for the inputs though.