# PHP PDO INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have very strange error with insert query to MySQL throught PDO.

I want insert record in table if this record doesnt exists in this table yet.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Phrases (KeyText)
            SELECT * FROM (SELECT :key_text) as tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Phrases WHERE KeyText = :key_text)";

    try
    {
        $preparedStatement = $db->prepare($query);
        foreach ($phrases as $phrase)
        {
            $preparedStatement->execute(array(':key_text' => $phrase));
            echo "-";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {  
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
```

It throws exeption: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object.

I dont understand where is my error in SQL command. Other pieces of code is correct because when I changed SQL command to other (for example: **SELECT :key_text as kt**) it works correctly.

Thanks for answers.

UPDATE:
The error is:

**[0] => HY000
[1] => 1096
[2] => No tables used**

How can I make correct SQL command for MySQL?
Variant with

```
INSERT INTO Phrases (KeyText)
SELECT :key_text WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Phrases WHERE KeyText = :key_text)
```

doesnt work in MySQL too.

UPDATE 2:

```
INSERT INTO Phrases (KeyText)
SELECT :key_text FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Phrases WHERE KeyText = :key_text)
```

This query with DUAL table works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your prepare call is failing, and you've simply assumed it succeeded.

Try

```
    $preparedStatement = $db->prepare($query) or die($db->errorInfo());
```

to catch the error.

Comment: whoops, sorry. should be $db->errorInfo(). I'll edit the answer.

Comment: The error is:  [0] => HY000
    [1] => 1096
    [2] => No tables used

Comment: Solution was founded in DUAL table. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

your update2 should work.

**ALTERNATIVE**:

have unique or primary key on field KeyText

```
ALTER TABLE `Phrases` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`KeyText`);
```

and then use query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Phrases (KeyText) VALUES (:key_text);
```

Regarding no changes being recorder please check that you have autocommit on or do `commit`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the `prepare` failed, hence you're attempting to call `execute` on an invalid object (not a prepared statement object like you're expecting). Check that the return value of `prepare` is in fact a `PDOStatement` object and not `FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Phrases (KeyText)
    SELECT :key_text
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Phrases WHERE KeyText = :key_text)
```

[SQL Server - How to insert a record and make sure it is unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267804/sql-server-how-to-insert-a-record-and-make-sure-it-is-unique)

Comment: I know, but your variant is not valid for mysql. You can check it owns.

Answer (score 0):

wrong:

```
insert into table 
  select * from (select 1 a, 2 b ) t 
  where not exists(select 1 from t2 where t2.c =2)
```

right:

```
insert into table
  select * from (select 1 a, 2 b union select 1 a, 2 b) t
  where not exists(select 1 from t2 where t2.c =2)
```