# MySQL - how to add unique INT value without using AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I have a MySQL table. I must be able to add unique INT values for speed which is not an AUTO_INCREMENT column.

```
CREATE TABLE ki
(
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , comp_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
  , speed INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  , position INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

  , PRIMARY KEY (id)

  , UNIQUE INDEX (comp_id, speed, position)
  , INDEX (comp_id)

  , FOREIGN KEY (comp_id)
      REFERENCES competitions (id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

I want to insert new rows.

```
INSERT INTO ki (comp_id, speed, position) VALUES (1, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO ki (comp_id, speed, position) VALUES (1, 2, 0)
INSERT INTO ki (comp_id, speed, position) VALUES (1, 3, 0)
INSERT INTO ki (comp_id, speed, position) VALUES (1, 3, 0) -- error
INSERT INTO ki (comp_id, speed, position) VALUES (2, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO ki (comp_id, speed, position) VALUES (2, 3, 0)
INSERT INTO ki (comp_id, speed, position) VALUES (2, 2, 0)
```

With each comp_id the values of speed begin from 1. The value of speed should always be comp_id's biggest speed value + 1.

In case `(1, 3, 0)` already exists, the insert should be `(1, max(speed) where comp_id = 1, 0)`. In other words, `(1, 4, 0)`.

I do not want to modify the existing rows.

How could I do this on my SQL query? As told, speed must be unique and this has to work if there are several inserts exactly at the same time.

Would the following way work and quarantee an unique speed value (values starting from 1) if there are several inserts at the same time?

```
INSERT INTO ki (comp_id, speed, position) 
VALUES (
   1, 
   COALESCE((SELECT MAX(ki2.speed)  
     FROM ki AS ki2 
     WHERE ki2.comp_id = 1 
   ), 1) + 1,
   0
)
```

Comment: I'm still looking for help.

Comment: Still looking for help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - How to insert a record and make sure it is unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267804/sql-server-how-to-insert-a-record-and-make-sure-it-is-unique)

Comment: If speed must be unique, then put a unique index on it.

Comment: @HLGEM Different comp_id's can have the same speed value.

Comment: @Martin I could not see the same question there.

Comment: @xms why is this question different? You're using numbers instead of strings but the concept is the same, you want a unique value without using the MySQL increment sytem.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql .  This is a basic problem that has been solved before. Read and research about it. It took me a minute to find this post; it more closely fits what you want.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Is `position` relevant to the question?  If not, please remove it from `UNIQUE` and other places.

Comment: Another approach:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issues

Answer (score 1):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO ki(comp_id, position, speed)
  SELECT 1, 0, max(speed)+1
  FROM ki
```

Beware! This has at least two pitfalls:

1. Inserting first row needs special handling of null values
2. More importantly, this can lead to race conditions, so you'd better use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for that which could lead to having gaps while insertion fails

While 1. pitfall is easy to deal with by wrapping it with `coalesce(max(speed),0)+1`, second pitfall is a real danger and normally you'd need to take this into account, or just create `UNIQUE INDEX` on `speed` column and have racing queries fail on any attempt but first with the same value.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `SELECT`...`max(speed)+1` will give me an unique value?

Comment: No, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I've mentioned this as well in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot write a query which does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you can't use autooincrement because you already have one of those?If speed must be unique, then why isn't it the PK on the table and get rid of the autoincrement column and autoincrement Speed instead?

However, if Speed should have meaning and be defined on insert then you have a different problem. In this case you define a unique index on speed and let it fail on insert if the value is already there. Or you write a stored proc to insert if the speed is not there and update the record if it is. Which you choose is a function of the meaning of the data and the business rules.